# How To Fuzzy Search?

Tags: soql

I want to perform a search where the `Name` field contains the `query` value.

```
public static Map<Id,Postal__c> getRecordsMap(
    String query,PostalRequest.cls_address address,Integer offsetCount,Integer limitCount
){
        return New Map<Id,Postal__c>([SELECT Id,Name FROM Postal__c
                                            WHERE Name LIKE :query 
                                                AND City__r.Name =:address.city
                                                AND Provinance__r.Name =:address.state
                                                AND Country__r.Name =: address.country
                                                LIMIT : limitCount 
                                                OFFSET :offsetCount]);
    }
```

Comment: If you don't know what's wrong with it, how are we supposed to figure it out? Are you getting any errors? Unexpected output? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing search in which you need to provide query string:

```
public static Map<Id,Postal__c> getRecordsMap(String query,PostalRequest.cls_address address,Integer offsetCount,Integer limitCount){
    query = '%' + query + '%';
    return New Map<Id,Postal__c>([SELECT Id,Name FROM Postal__c
                                        WHERE Name LIKE :query 
                                            AND City__r.Name =:address.city
                                            AND Provinance__r.Name =:address.state
                                            AND Country__r.Name =: address.country
                                            LIMIT : limitCount 
                                            OFFSET :offsetCount]);
}
```